# How to setup Log4j with Azure's ApplicationInsight appender in a Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2, azure-application-insights

I have a Spring Boot `1.5.8` setup with Log4j for logging purposes. I use Azure web services and Azure's Application Insights for logging purposes.

Questions

1. How to setup Azure to intercept HTTP requests in Spring Boot (i.e. annotation-based config) using `Logj4j`?
2. Why does my custom logs not show up in Application Insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly**, there is not much out there to show how to setup `Spring Boot` with `Log4j` and Application Insights. I think there is one or two tutorials on `Logback`.

**Secondly**, there seems to be some **issue|bug** in one or more versions of Azure's ApplicationInsights libraries (See link at the end).

To enable `Request-level` logging to Azure's `ApplicationInsights` in Spring Boot, we need to register the ApplicationInsights as follow

```
package com.sample;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryConfiguration;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.WebRequestTrackingFilter;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.spring")
public class AppInsightsConfig {
    private String insightsKey = "appInsightsKeyXX"; 

    @Bean
    public String telemetryConfig() {
        if (insightsKey != null) {
            TelemetryConfiguration.getActive().setInstrumentationKey(insightsKey);
        }
        return insightsKey;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean aiFilterRegistration() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(new WebRequestTrackingFilter());
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/**");
        registration.setOrder(1);
        return registration;
    } 

    @Bean(name = "WebRequestTrackingFilter")
    public Filter WebRequestTrackingFilter() {
        return new WebRequestTrackingFilter();
    }   
}
```

Above is the `annotation-config` equivalent of the following XML-based configuration

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>ApplicationInsightsWebFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
    com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.WebRequestTrackingFilter
  </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>ApplicationInsightsWebFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The above will config log all `http` requests to application insights - a basic request interceptor|filter.

I had to stick with the following version of `ApplicationInsights` jars

```
// application insights dependencies
compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'applicationinsights-core', version: '1.0.9'
compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'applicationinsights-web', version: '1.0.9'
compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'applicationinsights-logging-log4j1_2', version: '1.0.9'
```

Navigate to the comments section of this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-java-trace-logs) to see the issues that people experienced using different versions of `ApplicationInsights` with `Log4j 1.2` and `Log4j2`. For me only `1.0.9` worked.

Sharing in case others experience the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

@Raf yes there was a bug with Log4j and LogBack in the previous versions of Application Insights Java SDK. However with the latest SDK out on Maven which is 2.0.0-BETA we have fixed this issue. See the release notes here. Also thank you very much for putting down this example. I would try and include this in the microsoft docs repository.

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/releases/tag/v2.0.0-BETA

Comment: Also please feel free to file the issue if found on the usage on github repository. Is much easier to track though this one was a known bug and is now fixed

Comment: Please don't add extra information in a comment. Comments are for requesting clarification, and for replying to other comments. Put all relevant info in the actual answer.

Comment: Hello, I'm able to push the logs to AI using log4j 1.2 appender. But, in the end, my application is not exiting. It's because the Application Insights is still active. How can I stop Application Insights. I cannot use java's `System.exit()` method. Also, I've tried `TelemetryConfiguration.getActive().setTrackingIsDisabled(true)`. It is also not working. Can you please tell me how can I safe exit the application?